# Processing data for five weather stations

Tags: time-limit-exceeded, r

**Problem**

The main idea is to build some fine scale weather data using inverse distance weighting (idw) from the 5 closest stations of the observed station.  If the `value` in the `newdat` data set is greater than 134, less than -80, equal to -9999, or `NA` then run the function to get an interpolated value. If greater than 2 stations exist use idw, if only 1 station exists use the closest station, or if no close stations exist use the mean for the month of the year.

I'm trying to pass some information to a function I've created, have it run through some subsetting and calculations, then return the value to the point in the data frame that conditions were met.  It's quite a hack job, but I've got it working using a `for` loop; however, it takes a really long time on the regular data set .

The idea is to create a function `nearest()` that accepts 5 weather stations, stacks them, finds inverse distance weight, and then returns a value to the original data frame.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'd like a more R, or efficient way to do it hopefully with `data.table` or `dplyr` since they are optimized so well.  I think this can also be done with one of the `apply` functions, but I don't know how to code this.

**About the data**

In the original data set there are 7 data sets;  1 station as the center station which is called `station` in this example; and 5 closest stations (`s1`-`s5`). Each of the 5 stations have around 20-30k obs and the primary station `newdat` will have 18,627 -- one for each day between 1900 and 1950. This isn't so bad as I have over 600 stations for this computation and each one takes around 15 minutes (15 minutes per station x 600 stations = 6.25 days). The next round will have over 12,000 stations, so this is just a warm up and I think I should be able to reuse the code.

In this example, I have scraped all the local stations (`s1`-`s5`) down to just one subset of the data The nearest station (`station`) has also been subset out to a single observation.  The main data set `newdat` has also been reduced down to just 10 observations with an `NA` value and a value over 200.  The goal is to replace both of those values using the function `nearest()`.

The flow of the data looks like this:

1. Load individual station id (`newdat`-lists all dates, and 5 closest stations (`s1-s5`)
2. For an individual station check the `value` variable for each day for conditions described above (e.g. outlier, NA, or -9999)
3. When condition is met, grab the location in the data frame of element, year, month, and day from `newdat`.
4. Subset `s1-s5` based on those criteria (this will leave 1 or 0 obs for each `s1-s5`
5. Stack `s1-s5` and use either idw if greater than 2 obs exist, use single station if only 1 obs exists, or mean of the month and year if no obs exist
6. If using idw, it is necessary to use the lat/long for `station` and (`s1-s5`).
7. Use this value to plug in to `newdat` where the `value` was found to be an outlier, NA, or -9999.
8. Move on to next day

**dput (need all):**

```
newdat <- structure(list(id = c("USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", "USC00031632", 
"USC00031632", "USC00031632"), element = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("TMAX", "TMIN"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c("1900", "1900", "1900", "1900", "1900", "1900", 
    "1900", "1900", "1900", "1900"), month = c("01", "01", "02", 
    "02", "03", "04", "04", "05", "05", "01"), day = c("01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02"), date = structure(c(-25567, 
    -25567, -25536, -25536, -25508, -25477, -25477, -25447, -25447, 
    -25566), class = "Date"), value = c(30.02, 28, 37.94, 10.94, 
    200, 25, 41, 82.04, 51.08, NA)), .Names = c("id", "element", 
"year", "month", "day", "date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")

s1 <- structure(list(id = "USC00031152", element = "TMAX", year = 1900, 
    month = 1, day = 2, date = structure(-25566, class = "Date"), 
    value = 37.04, y = 33.59, x = -92.8236), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value", "y", "x"))

s2 <- structure(list(id = "USC00034638", element = "TMAX", year = 1900, 
    month = 1, day = 2, date = structure(-25566, class = "Date"), 
    value = 62.06, y = 34.7392, x = -90.7664), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value", "y", "x"))

s3 <- structure(list(id = "USC00036352", element = "TMAX", year = 1900, 
    month = 1, day = 2, date = structure(-25566, class = "Date"), 
    value = 30.92, y = 35.2833, x = -93.1), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value", "y", "x"))

s4 <- structure(list(id = "USC00036248", element = "TMAX", year = 1900, 
    month = 1, day = 2, date = structure(-25566, class = "Date"), 
    value = 30.02, y = 36.3667, x = -94.1), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value", "y", "x"))

s5 <- structure(list(id = "USC00035112", element = "TMAX", year = 1900, 
    month = 1, day = 2, date = structure(-25566, class = "Date"), 
    value = -9999, y = 33.9294, x = -93.8583), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"element", "year", "month", "day", "date", "value", "y", "x"))

station <- structure(list(id = "USC00030528", lat = 35.45, long = -92.4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = c("id", "lat", "long"))
```

**Function:**

```
nearest <- function(id, yr, mnt, dy, ele, s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3, s4=s4, s5=s5, out=output, station=station){

  s1_d <- filter(s1, year == yr & month == mnt  & day == dy & element == ele)
  s2_d <- filter(s2, year == yr & month == mnt  & day == dy & element == ele)
  s3_d <- filter(s3, year == yr & month == mnt  & day == dy & element == ele)
  s4_d <- filter(s4, year == yr & month == mnt  & day == dy & element == ele)
  s5_d <- filter(s5, year == yr & month == mnt  & day == dy & element == ele)

  s1_d <- select(s1_d, id, x, y, value)
  s2_d <- select(s2_d, id, x, y, value)
  s3_d <- select(s3_d, id, x, y, value)
  s4_d <- select(s4_d, id, x, y, value)
  s5_d <- select(s5_d, id, x, y, value)

  stack <- do.call("rbind", list(s1_d, s2_d, s3_d, s4_d, s5_d))
  stack <- select(stack, id, x, y, value)
  stack <- filter(stack, value != -9999)

  if (dim(stack)[1] >= 1){
    ifelse(dim(stack)[1] == 1, v <- stack$value, v <- idw(stack$value, stack[,2:4], station[,2:3])) 
  } else {
    ret <- filter(out, id == id & year == yr, month == mnt, element == ele, value != -9999)
    v <- mean(ret$value) 
  } 
  return(v)
}
```

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(phylin)
library(lubridate)   
 for(j in which(is.na(newdat$value) | newdat$value > 134 | newdat$value < -80 | newdat$value == -9999)) {
        newdat[j,7] <- nearest(id = j, yr = as.numeric(newdat[j,3]), mnt = as.numeric(newdat[j,4]), dy = as.numeric(newdat[j,5]),
                               ele = as.character(newdat[j,2]), s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3,s4=s4,s5=s5, out=newdat, station=station)
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Good job on your first post!

Comment: Hello, for us to get a sense of the slow computation times you are experiencing, could you please provide the dimensions of all the objects in your real application?

Comment: @flodel See edit in question.  Hope this makes it more clear

Comment: I have no knowledge and experience in R (so I don't know exactly how stuff works), but my guess is that the bottleneck is due to the search/filtering of data in the `nearest` function. From what I can understand, they are not sorted data. If you can sort the data before calling the `nearest` function you could apply a binary search or something similar.

Comment: @GentianKasa Yes, I've done some profiling on the code and the filtering is certainly part of the bottle neck, but I don't see a way around this because of the way the code works.  The stations are already loaded for each local station, but it still needs to filter out based on element, year, month, day from the point in `newdat`.

Comment: Could you share some more info regarding the dataflow in your application?

Comment: @GentianKasa I updated the question to describe the flow of the data.  Hope it is more clear.

Comment: It's a tad more clear, but I need another kind of information. I'm going with more specific questions. You have a central station that does some calculation (not particularly interested in what it is for now) with the data that 5 surrounding stations send it, right? Is this data aggregated in some way or is it treated independently? The data is also split among 600 stations if I understood correctly, right? If so, is it split randomly or with some logic based on the data? And, a question not related to the data, but to my ignorance on the matter, what are obs?

Comment: Anyway, the basic idea is to sort the data (whenever makes sense for your application: before they are sent to the central station, or before/after aggregating, or in another moment) before processing them. The sorting by year, then by month, and finally by day can be done in \$O(n)\$, so it doesn't add to the overall complexity. Once you've done that you can do a binary search on the data (and here's where you gain in complexity, from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(log(n))\$). After that you just proceed with the rest of the computation.

Comment: @GentianKasa Yes, the 5 closest weather stations are independent and in order to compute `idw` the function needs lat/long and the values.  The data for all stations is aggregated into one data frame and then the idea is to iterate through all of that data to find when outliers, NA, or -9999 are found.  At this point, it searches for the closest stations and computes the necessary value.  I have thought about the sort and if there is another way to do this, but because it is more of a search and the need to stack the data to find `idw` makes this a bit more complex.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a bit more. Something that I'm still having having difficulties understanding from the description is the role of the 600 (that should become 12000) stations that you mention. And one more question: from the profiling you've made, what are other operations that need fine tuning (whose performance is not so good)?

Comment: @GentianKasa The increase in station size is simply a scaling effect I will have later with some additional data.  It is not relevant to this problem as long as the code scales well.  The profiling primarily focuses on the filtering, but as I've said this something I don't know how to get around.

Comment: One way to make filtering more convenient could be to make the 5 nearest stations send you the data already sorted by year, then by month, then by day. This operation can be done in \$O(n)\$ by using an algorithm like Counting Sort. This way, the complexity of this operation is split among the stations. When aggregating the data you can apply a merge algorithm to maintain sorting. The search (even for an interval) on a sorted set, as I'm sure you already know, can be done in \$O(log n)\$ by using Binary Search. Can I ask you to keep us updated on how you solved the problem when you solve it?

Comment: I feel binding the stations df before subset would improve the workflow by avoiding multiple filter/select calls. According to your description, it would make a df under 200k rows which should not be problem to fit in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go further than my comment:

You're filtering twice for the same datas and so repeating yourself a lot in your nearest function, this could be simplified in a one call subset and avoid too much context switches.

This is how I would write your function:

```
nearest2 <- function(id,yr,mnt,dy,ele,s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3, s4=s4, s5=s5, out=output, station=station){
  stations <- rbind(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)
  stack <- with(stations,stations[year==yr & month==mnt & day==dy & element==ele & value!=-9999,c("id","x","y","value")])
  if (dim(stack)[1] >= 1){
    ifelse(dim(stack)[1] == 1, v <- stack$value, v <- idw(stack$value, stack[,2:4], station[,2:3])) 
  } else {
    ret <- filter(out, id == id & year == yr, month == mnt, element == ele, value != -9999)
    v <- mean(ret$value) 
  } 
  return(v)
}
```

As you can see the idea is not really different, I stick to base R but feel free to prefer `filter %>% select` approach.

To test the results I created 2 functions calling your orignal code and mine:

```
original <- function() {
  for(j in which(is.na(newdat$value) | newdat$value > 134 | newdat$value < -80 | newdat$value == -9999)) {
    nearest(id = j, yr = as.numeric(newdat[j,3]), mnt = as.numeric(newdat[j,4]), dy = as.numeric(newdat[j,5]),
                           ele = as.character(newdat[j,2]), s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3,s4=s4,s5=s5, out=newdat, station=station)
  }
}

refactored <- function() {
  for(j in which(is.na(newdat$value) | newdat$value > 134 | newdat$value < -80 | newdat$value == -9999)) {
    nearest2(id = j, yr = as.numeric(newdat[j,3]), mnt = as.numeric(newdat[j,4]), dy = as.numeric(newdat[j,5]),
                           ele = as.character(newdat[j,2]), s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3,s4=s4,s5=s5, out=newdat, station=station)
  }
}
```

And then I did benchmark them to see if it improves or not:

```
> microbenchmark(original(),refactored(),times=10L)
Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   original() 10.324189 10.612698 12.101344 11.366187 12.554720 17.544906    10
 refactored()  1.774676  1.831978  2.452274  2.527737  2.769064  3.222069    10
```

I think an average gain of 6 times is kind of an interesting improvement, but this has to be confirmed on your real datas.

Concerning your main for loop, it does not sound that bad as working on specific values and not growing a vector (implying memory copies) in it's content, moving to `sapply` can bring a little gain on large vectors at end.

Example with your sample datas:

```
refactored2 <- function() {
  sapply(
    which(is.na(newdat$value) | newdat$value > 134 | newdat$value < -80 | newdat$value == -9999),
    function(j) {
      nearest2(id = j, yr = as.numeric(newdat[j,3]), mnt = as.numeric(newdat[j,4]), dy = as.numeric(newdat[j,5]),
               ele = as.character(newdat[j,2]), s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3,s4=s4,s5=s5, out=newdat, station=station)
    })
}
```

Benchmark result, the overhead of sapply is visible for a small vector (2 values actually) here, this should improve with larger input in favor of sapply:

```
> microbenchmark(original(),refactored(),refactored2(),times=10L)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    original() 9.587806 11.258994 11.862497 11.979840 12.065223 13.659437    10
  refactored() 1.840816  2.071738  2.892308  2.554820  3.360622  5.995409    10
 refactored2() 1.853931  2.664436  2.967314  3.144811  3.234328  3.925097    10
```

I assumed you don't wish to change your original `newdat` observations types, if you can accept it, turn the year, month and day to numeric before processing to avoid multiple calls.

Lastly, you're testing year, month and day separately for equality, maybe getting rid of them and comparing the date field directly could be a potential improvement too (or using POSIXct class for the date field and work with date functions if your need time ranges).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this!  The benchmark greatly improves the performance of this.  I've improved the code further outside of this and have no included sapply as you suggest.  However, the `bind` then `sort` does make a lot more sense, so I'll try that on the dataset.  Ironically, I'm been running this code for 7 days now on the original data and should finish today.  I'll report back with improvements on the original.  Thanks!